# Should I connect one or both Ufer grounds to my panel?

Tags: electrical, grounding-and-bonding

Local code requires the use of a [Ufer ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ufer_ground) (concrete-encased electrode) as a ground rod system for new construction. There are two electrodes in my construction. My question is: do I connect both electrodes with a single conductor to my sub panel or just one of the electrodes?

Comment: Welcome to SE, Jerry. Hope you don't mind the edits for clarity. Feel free to edit further. Please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if you're new to the SE concept.

Comment: As Ed Beal points the NEC code allows bonding of the closest one. Make sure however if you intend to ever use that other one for anything - bond it to the panel as well, If you don't you can get ground loops which is not a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

You only have to bond the closest one to the panel. NEC 250.52.a.3.2. (2017) same in the 2014 code.

Comment: "***250.52(A)(3) Concrete-Encased Electrode.** ... If multiple concrete-encased electrodes are present at a building or structure, it shall be permissible to bond only one into the grounding electrode system.*"